# JavaScript MaxLength not working on new textfields

Tags: javascript, input, textfield, maxlength

I add new text fields with Javascript:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.name = "blabla";
input.maxlength = '4';
input.size = "4";
input.id = "blabla";
container.appendChild(input);
```

It appears maxlength doesn't do anything..I have tried "" '' or without any quotations. What's wrong? In chrome when I inspect element I get:

> `<input type="text" name="blabla" size="4" id="blabla">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `maxLength` not `maxlength`

```
input.maxLength = 4;
```

Note about the `L`.

Comment: Wow, i could have sworn i tried that, but looks like i didn't Thanks